# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Не могу прочитать список файлов

Tags: python, json

Всем привет!
Хочу прочитать несколько файлов JSON из папки.

```
import json
import openpyxl
import os
from pathlib import Path

path_to_json = Path('promo')

for file_name in [file for file in os.listdir(path_to_json) if file.endswith('.json')]:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        print(data)
```

При запуске получаю ошибку

```
"C:\Python 396\python.exe" "C:/Users/TheRealVVD/Desktop/тестовое задание/тестовое задание/script.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TheRealVVD\Desktop\тестовое задание\тестовое задание\script.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'export_20210913-1649_435_7429.json'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в заключается ошибка кода и как мне ее решить?

Пример взял отсюда (https://coderoad.ru/30539679/Python-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-json-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

P.S. "script.py" находится в той же директории, что и папка "promo", т.е. во второй папке "тестовое задание"

Comment: А папка, в которой находится скрипт и текущая папка при запуске этого скрипта - это не одно и тоже. Лучше передавайте скрипту полный путь к папке в аргументах. Ну или переходите в нужную папку перед запуском скрипта. Или если через ярлык запускаете, то там можно прописать "рабочий каталог".

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: @CrazyElf Кажется понял, о чем Вы говорите. Могли бы подсказать, пожалуйста, как мне указать путь для открытия файла, а не для поиска?
Потому что файлы я могу найти, но пытаюсь открыть их относительно своего скрипта, а он - в другой директории)

Comment: @CrazyElf потому что добавляя путь, получаю ошибку: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'"

Comment: Попробуйте через дробь / вместо + пути соединять

Comment: Хотя в вашем случае вообще всё что я выше там сказал нерелевантно, если у вас os.listdir нормально отработал, я что-то поторопился. Но скорее всего да, нужно соединить путь и имя файла, имя файла без пути перебирается. Попробуйте через дробь. )

Comment: @CrazyElf перед "open" добавил:
file_name = os.path.join(path_to_json, file_name) - все заработало
сейчас попробую Ваш совет!

Comment: Просто у pathlib вроде соединение путей через /, а так да, os.path.join работает. У меня впечатление что я вам только мешаю )

Comment: @CrazyElf любой совет нагоняет на мысли) 
Снова нашел решение через pathlib - выглядит короче и приятнее)